# How to add new variable averaging across cross references?

Tags: r, database

I have a data set that has the average Math and English scores for every school district in the nation, grade 3-8 for 5 years. I'm looking to create a new variable that would be the average test score for the district for each given year regardless of grade. I'd like to eliminate the grade variable entirely. Each district has a unique leaid provided by common core.

My dataset is df_stat and my variables are:
mean_link_math
mean_link_ela
leaid
grade
year

I have been pretty lost in trying to attempt it. I can do it one observation at a time but with over 300,000 observations I'd rather not use this approach

Comment: Hi Kyle Heideman. Please help make this a reproducible question by editing it to include a sample of the dataset. An easy way to do this is copying the output from `dput(head(df_stat))` and pasting it into a codeblock in your question.

Comment: Wouldn’t this need the class sizes in order to properly weight the averages of averages calculations.?